# Pythonic way for check and poll mechanism

Tags: if-statement, python

What is the pythonic way of checking if multiple sub strings are present in the string?

For eg. I'm doing poll and check on the download status through API. The API returns status as "Download complete", "x% Downloaded" or "Installing".

Now, I want to check if 'downloaded' and 'installing' strings are present in status returned by API and if not, raise exception. I have implemented this by very novice way.

```
if api_object.status == 'Download Complete'  :
        break

elif 'Downloaded' in api_object.status.split():
        time.sleep(interval)

elif 'Downloaded' not in api_object.status.split() or \
'Installing' not in api_object.status.split():
        raise Exception("Error")
```

I would like to know any better approaches for comparison.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be useful to show your current implementation.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me, although using `split` is superfluous, as Amber demonstrates below.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more compact version:

```
if api_object.status == 'Download Complete':
    break
elif 'Downloaded' in api_object.status:
    time.sleep(interval)
elif 'Installing' not in api_object.status:
    raise Exception("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code is "pythonic" or not, but it is easy to understand and that's what matters most, even if it is a bit longer. Check the following "more pythonic" way:

```
....
elif all([(x not in status) for x in ['Downloaded', 'Installing'] ]):
....
```

does it read better?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
status = api_object.status.partition(" ");
try:
    action = {
        "Downloaded": doA
        "Complete": doB
        "Installing": doC
    }[status[2] or status[0]]
except KeyError:
    # unknown status
    raise
action();
```

Using a dict is a common idiom in python to replace a missing switch-statement. doA through doC shall be callables, which you call in the last line. Using the [partition(sep)](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) method and the `or` operator, one can easily pick the correct part of the string: If it exists, one gets the part behind the space, otherwise one gets the whole string.

One should note though, that caching the dictionary might be useful in a performance critical application to safe time for hashing the keys and building the dict.

For case insensitive matching, one would call [lower()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) on the status string (before partition) and put the keys to lower case.

In this particular case, a `break` is required. One could do this by allowing the callable to return a boolean value, which, if `True`, triggers a `break` or a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code :

```
if 'Download Complete'  == api_object.status:
    break       
if 'Installing' == api_object.status:
    continue
if api_object.status and api_object.status.endswith('Downloaded'):
    time.sleep(interval)
else:
    raise Exception("Error")
```